# "Above the fold" window size averages

Tags: html, css, resolution, screen-resolution

It's generally agreed that 1024x768 browsers are the target, with 960 - 980px widths being acceptable. (I personally prefer 960 for the chrome, but no point in arguing.)

My question is - what *window height* can one generally assume of users? I know this varies depending on a number of things, so I'm curious if anyone's done any studies on what heights can be designed for in order to reach x % of users.

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google created a website that shows you what percentage of people will see your web page upon loading.

http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/

Comment: Wow, so something like 50% of web users don't see the entire skyscraper (600px) ad at the same time. Crazy ;P

Comment: Just remember, the average user knows to scroll down a webpage. So if your content falls below the fold, most will still find what they're looking for. Vertical scrolling is acceptable, but horizontal scrolling should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 5):

As of June 4, 2012, Google has moved the "graduated" browsersize.googlelabs.com tool inside of Google Analytics. Simply navigate to the Content section in Google Analytics, and click In-Page Analytics.

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/06/new-feature-conduct-browser-size.html

:)